# ASP.NET MVC 5 center textbox css

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the textbox that comes with the default MVC template and is defined like:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtVideo", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I'm trying to center this on the screen and being able to play with the width to get the size I want. I tried with the below but the textbox just doesn't get any bigger. How can I play with the width size of this textbox that the default MVC template creates?

```
<div style="width:100%; background-color: Green;">
    <div style="display: table; margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; background-color: Red;">
        @Html.TextBox("txtVideo", null, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width: 100%;" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBox("txtVideo", null, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "margin: 0px auto; width: 600px;" })
```

Comment: Then you should provide more context about the wrapping elements and CSS you are using. Some other CSS might be interfering with it. In a new ASP.NET MVC application this works fine. Ideally provide a http://jsfiddle.net illustrating the problem.

Comment: I just put what you have right into an empty page. It would seem "form-control" is causing the issue as when I remove that then it works. However, I like the visuals they have for the textbox for that class in the default MVC project. I guess I'll have to see what about that class makes it left justified.

Comment: Well, I've placed that in an empty view and it worked as expected. It worked with or without the `form-control` style.

Comment: Did your view use the default _layout? I'm not very good with css so I'm trying to figure out why mine would still be left justified.

Comment: Yes, the default `_Layout.cshtml` that was created with the project.

Comment: OK, then I'm stumped as to why mine isn't centered.

Comment: Maybe if you could provide a jsfiddle illustrating the problem we might be able to help.

Comment: This is the problem. Literally just the code you have listed above I'm trying to center on the page and it's left justified. There is no other code to show. I'm simply testing this centering of the textbox.

Comment: OK, here are the steps: Create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project using the Internet Application template. In `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` put the code shown in my answer. Hit F5.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I have, which is why it's not making sense to me. I deleted all of Index.cshtml and put just your code above. Is it me or is jfiddler down? Was going to try this without the .NET stuff to see what's up.

Comment: No, don't delete Index.cshtml. Start an entirely **new** ASP.NET MVC 4 application in Visual Studio using the Internet Application template.

Comment: It's so strange, when I have just <input> code it works. It just has to be something related to the class. Actually I think my project is MVC 5. I wonder if they changed the css between 4 & 5.

Comment: Hmm, maybe. Let me try with ASP.NET MVC 5. The css has changed quite a lot. You should have tagged your question more appropriately with the specific version you are using.

Comment: Yep there is a difference. It works in MVC 4. Any ideas on MVC 5?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer with an example of how to achieve that in ASP.NET MVC 5.

Comment: So the interesting thing about that is that the width on there doesn't seem to change no matter what value I put on it.

Comment: Ah OK, so Bootstrap is a framework. Thanks for the info Darin!

Comment: Yes, it's a CSS and javascript framework that's built-in ASP.NET MVC 5.